# Invalid syntax in format string on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decided to learn Linux for myself and program in its environment. I downloaded Sublime text, created a file, launched it in the terminal.
Aaaaand got this in response:

```
File "hello_world.py", line 12
return f"  FLOAT: {self.__arg}\t\tINT: {self.a}"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what it can be connected with, because on Windows everything works wonderfully for me.
Perhaps this is due to some feature of Linux?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
class Float(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):    #construc
        self.__arg = arg
        self.a = arg

    @property                   #geter
    def getarg(self):
        return self.__arg

    def __str__(self):
        return f"  FLOAT: {self.__arg}\t\tINT: {self.a}"

    def display_info(self):
        print(f"\nЧисло: {self.__arg}")

    def rozdel(self):           #division into whole and fractional parts
        self.a = int(self.__arg)
        self.b = self.__arg - int(self.__arg)
        print(f"\nInteger part: {self.a}, Fractional part: {self.b}")
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print(f"\nStarted number: {self.c}")

    def __lt__(self, other):    #overloading <
        return self.__arg < other.__arg

    def __getitem__(self, index): #overloading []
        print(f"  {self.b}")

#------------------------------------------------------------------
def SortArr(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[min]:
                min = j
        arr[i], arr[min] = arr[min], arr[i]
#------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(input("Enter count of elements: "))

    j = 0
    arr = []
    for i in range(size):
        j += 1
        print("---------------------")
        print("Variant %d" %(j))
        a = float(input("Enter float number: "))
        arr.append(Float(a))
        arr[i].display_info()
        arr[i].rozdel()

    SortArr(arr)
    print("\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-")
    print("Data after sorting:")
    for i in range(size):
        print(str(arr[i]))
    print("-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-\n")
    print("Selection of the fractional part: ")
    for i in range(size):
        arr[i][0]
    print("-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-\n")
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? Many Debian-derived distros reserve the name `python` for Python 2, and use `python3` for Python 3.

Comment: Kali is a specialized distribution which is most decidedly not suitable for learning Linux.

Comment: The f-strings syntax is only valid in Python 3.6+.  Which version of Python are you using?  May I (also) recommend learning Linux on a more generalised distribution, such as Ubuntu or Mint.  Some of the tools you may become accustomed to in Kali, might not be available in a more ‘standardised’ distribution which you might more regularly use in your programming life; and visa versa.

Comment: @tripleee, before running the program, I specifically installed python3(`apt-get install python3`)

Comment: python --version; python3 --version; also you can mess up the OS if you get rid of its python. If you want to run python3 as "python" then first create and activate a venv for it.

Comment: @Sollpix You may have Python 3 installed, but you haven't given any indication you are actually *using* it.

Comment: @chepner, aaand what I need to do for that?

Comment: @S3DEV, I have the latest version of pythin(3.10.5)

Comment: It's simple: how are you actually executing the code? The error message you show is what you would get trying to use an f-string prior to Python 3.6, so the simplest explanation is that you are *not* executing the script with Python 3.10.5.

Comment: Multiple commenters here have told you how to update your question. If the duplicate doesn't solve your problem, please finally [edit] to provide the requested details and we may be able to reopen this.